# Where can I find option expiry data on DTCC directly?

Tags: options, foreign-exchange

I know that many news networks like Reuters or some forums report daily (sometimes weekly) about upcoming FX options expiry for NY cut, citing DTCC. However, I navigated around on the DTCC website but couldn't find any information how to check it directly on their website. 
Highly appreciate if anybody could provide insight.

Answer (score 1):

US Exchange listed options information is generally provided by The Options Clearing Corporation rather than DTCC.  DTCC generally clears stock and not options.